# Find and Delete a Sub-String in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to find a Java sub-string and then delete it without deleting the rest of the string.

I am taking XML as input and would like to delete a deprecated tag, so for instance:

```
public class whatever {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String uploadedXML = "<someStuff>Bats!</someStuff> <name></name>";
    CharSequence deleteRaise = "<name>";

    // If an Addenda exists we continue with the process    
    if (xml_in.contains(deleteRaise)){
        // delete
    } else {
        // Carry on
    }
}
```

In there I would like to delete the `<name>` and `</name>` tags if they are included in the string while leaving `<someStuff>` and `</someStuff>`.

I already parsed the XML to a String so there's no problem there. I need to know how to find the specific strings and delete them.

Comment: Try `replace` method in `String` class.

Comment: Submit it as an answer please, that was pretty much all I needed. So I'd like to give the valid answer.

Comment: What do you mean, "parsed XML to a String"? Also, any reason you don't use an XML parser for XML manipulation, such as Xerces? Manipulating XML by regexp is... [dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Filtering of the XML will be more efficient if it is done prior to converting the XML to a string. With XSLT it is possible to filter out all the `<name>` tags and make other alternations as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll(regex, str)` to do this. If you're not familiar with regex, the `?` just means there can be `0 or 1` occurrences of `/` in the string, so it covers `<name>` and `</name>`

```
String uploadedXML = "<someStuff>Bats!</someStuff> <name></name>";
String filter = "</?name>";
uploadedXML = uploadedXML.replaceAll(filter, "");

System.out.println(uploadedXML);
```

---

```
 <someStuff>Bats!</someStuff>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String uploadedXML = "<someStuff>Bats!</someStuff> <name></name>";
String deleteRaise = "<name>";
String closeName = "</name>"
// If an Addenda exists we continue with the process    
if (xml_in.contains(deleteRaise)){
    uploadedXML.replace(uploadedXML.substring(uploadedXML.indexOf(deleteRaise),uploadedXML.indexOf(closeName)+1),"");
} else {
    // Carry on
}enter code here
```